# Получить имя пользователя WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, wordpress-плагины

Пишу плагин, и необходимо получить имя текущего пользователя. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать? Плагин уже установлен на сайт, осталось только вывести пользователя..

Comment: Пробовали https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user ?

Comment: @br3t да, блин, печаль.. современные писатели плагинов и тем ни то, что про кодекс не знают, но даже не позравают о необходимости хотя бы загуглить используемые фунции.

Comment: Ну так я различные варианты пробовал - не получается. Решил тут помощи попросить

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен логин пользователя, то так:

```
echo wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
```

Код рабочий. В качестве проверки вставьте такой тест в самый низ functions.php, например:

```
function action_footer() {
  echo wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_footer' );
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Comment: Код правильный. Я даже его протестировал). Работает.

Comment: Я даже не представляю, как функция может быть не определена. А другие функции при этом работают?

Comment: А вы куда этот код добавили? В какой файл?

Comment: он работает везде. вопрос в том, куда вы его добавляете. у вас что-то со структурой плагина, не может эта функция был не определена, если WordPress инициализирован. А он инициализирован, поскольку именно ядро вызывает плагин.

Comment: дал вам пример, как эта функция работает, дополнил ответ

Comment: `wp_get_current_user() находится в /wp-includes/pluggable.php, а этот файл подключается сразу после загрузки плагинов, но до события plugins_loaded. Поэтому нельзя вызывать эту и зависящие от нее функции прямо из кода плагина. Их нужно вызывать через хук plugins_loaded, init или позднее`.https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_current_user

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
  global $current_user;
  if( ! is_object( $current_user ) ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  }
  echo $current_user->first_name;  // выведет имя пользователя
}
```